# Write to txt file from matlab

Tags: matlab, text, ascii

I'm needing to create a .txt file from matlab for a school homework assignment.  The format of the file is a little arbitrary.  Needs to have one of my variables on the first line.  The time on the second line.  Some text, then another variable value on the third line.  All followed by a matrix that I need to add headers to.

Does anyone know of a good tutorial or article that gives an overview of this kind of stuff?  I've found a couple and have heard of fprintf() and think I have a pretty good idea of how to proceed.  But I'm still a little stumped on how to do the matrix.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The "matrix" can be a cell matrix since the arguments are from different types. I.e.: `myVariableMatrix = {variable1 variable2, variable3; 'variableTime1', 'variableTime2', 'variableTime3'; 'someTextForVariable1', 'someTextForVariable2', 'someTextForVariable3'};`

Use `fprintf` for each line as follows: `fprintf(fid,'%d %s %s',myVariableMatrix{line,:})`. 

Of course, there are several ways of doing it.

Comment: you can use [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) with `'-append'`

Comment: you had the start of a good question about [restricting input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29241316) but deleted it too soon.  You should refine it to add more detail and some code showing what you are doing if you want an answer

Comment: Just put it back.  I figured something out and added my answer.  I only deleted it because that guy down voted it and I was ashamed :).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create a txt file in matlab and print some variables to it:

```
fid = fopen( 'my_file.txt', 'wt' );
fprintf( fid, '%f,%f,%f,%f\n', a1, a2, a3, a4);
fclose(fid);
```