# Restrict numeric input vb property grid

Tags: vb.net, enums

I have a variable that can only be set to certain numbers (integers and decimals) and that gets assigned by the user using a property grid.  What I want is something that behaves like an Enum, where the users can select from a a drop down list of acceptable values.  However enums don't see to support non integer numeric input.  Any ideas?

Comment: yep, we have some ideas.

Comment: Thanks.  What are they?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing get/set and just changing the value if it's outside the acceptable range.

```
<DataMember()>
<DisplayName("Fisheye Angle")>
<Description("This value indicates the angle used in the fisheye view, if it is enabled.  The acceptable range is 45 to 360 degrees with 180 degrees being the default. ")>
<DefaultValue(180)>
Public Property FisheyeAngle As Double
    Get
        Return _FisheyeAngle
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        If value < 45 Then
            _FisheyeAngle = 45
        ElseIf value > 360 Then
            _FisheyeAngle = 360
        Else
            _FisheyeAngle = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```